# vertical centred and horizontal top-aligned position fixed element

Tags: html, css

I am coming up with a jQuery notification system for a website I am building and I need the notification banner to be top aligned horizontally and vertically centered on the page.

I figured out the top alignment, but I can't get the vertical center.

I've tried `margin:0 auto;`, `left:50%;`, `left:50%;` and `right:50%;`, but none of those work.

The only thing that seems to work is estimating the center like `left:40%;`, but that only works at one viewport / resolution and I need something responsive.

How can I centre the notification vertically?

You can trigger the notification in the jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/f85eZ/ , by clicking anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the width of your `.notification-board` to be in percentage. Because `.notification-board` is your parent container. For example:

```
.notification-board{
    width:50%;
    ...
}
```

Then create a new class for centering with left calculated as half:

```
.notification-board.center{
    left: 25%;
}
```

See this updated fiddle of yours: **http://jsfiddle.net/f85eZ/2/**

And yes, I changed the click handler to initialize the creation like this:

```
$('*').on('click', function() {
    $.createNotification({
        horizontal:'center',
        vertical:'top',
        ...
```

Notice that it is *horizontally* center and *vertically* top. (Not horizontally top and vertically center!)

Comment: but I don't want the notification to take a width of 50% of the viewport, I only want it to take the space of the notification message.

Comment: You have already set the width to 250px, which means you have a fixed width and not according to the message length? Am I right?

Comment: yes, that is because, the message is only one message in this site and it can be a fixed width. So if you can get it working with a fixed width, that is fine.

Comment: Great. Then fixing the width at 50% works fine. See the fiddle I posted. You can change the width to any percentage that suits you, just halve that for `left` in your `.notification-board.center` class.

Comment: Moreover, even if somehow it is made elastic to message length, then what will happen if the message length exceeds the page width? It has to wrap. So, better have a fixed width and let the message wrap anyway. That way your options of left, center, right will all work beautifully.

Comment: Thank you. The JSFiddle is working perfectly for me! This JS Fiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/f85eZ/7/. However, when I implement it on my site, the notification is left some and not centred. Here is the site:  http://goo.gl/NfEr9u . Click anywhere, particularly the grey background to trigger the notification.

Comment: That is because: (1) the width for `.center` class should not be 25% if your board width is 42%. Calculate it like this: (100 - board / 2). So if your board width is 42%, then `.center` width would be 29%. (2) on your website, you have provided max-width as 242px. So the resultant width is much less than 42%. Keep the max-width also in percentage which should be >= width.

Answer (score 0):

I added only `left:50%;` to your `.notification-board > .notification` and it works fine!!

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/5N9E3/

Comment: It works well in most places, but not in small viewports. What do you suggest I do there?

Comment: @Mayank: will it work when the `createnotification` is initialized with option for top-right?

Comment: @gomangomango : if responsiveness is your concern, `media-query` is something you should consider! :)

Comment: @abhitalks : it should...is it not??

Answer (score 0):

try this css this work on all viewport / resolution as you need at center point .

```
  .notification-board{
    width:auto;
    font-family:'a', 'iconFont', 'Roboto Slab', 'Myriad Pro', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    margin:auto;
    display:table;
  }

  .notification-board > .notification{
     background:#000000;
     background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
     background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
     border-radius:6px;
     color:#ffffff;
     color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
     padding:16px;
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
     width:auto;
     margin:auto;

  }
```

see this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/f85eZ/8/

Comment: yes, but that gives the notification a width of the whole viewport. The three requirements I need are that it is top-centred, it only extends the width of the content of the notification and no more, and works in all viewports.

Comment: @gomangomango now see the code and jsfiddle i updated now it is in top-centred and it is also auto width as your content of notification it complete your all requirments.

Comment: @jigneshkheni: This doesn't work when options to `createnotification` are changed to top-left or top-right.

Comment: @abhitalks i check it works fine with me. can you provide me jsfiddle of that ?

Comment: @jigneshkheni: Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f85eZ/10/ Scroll down the javascript, and see where the `createnotification` is called with `horizontal:'right'` and `vertical:'top'` options. It is still showing the notification as centered instead of right-aligned.

Comment: horizontal and vertical option is  also not work in gomangomango jsfiddle this option is not working properly. see your answer fiddle if you remove left:25% and add left:0; notification is in not center. although your js option of createnotification is set to center. @abhitalks

Comment: @jigneshkheni You are missing the point. In my fiddle, if you change the javascript (not css) and provide different options, the notification would change its alignment accordingly. That is the point of a javascript plugin/utlity. You should not be required to change the css. Different parameters/options should work. In fact, your earlier answer was better. Without fixed width, this won't work.

Comment: @jigneshkheni Its working. Open this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f85eZ/2/ Now scroll the javascript to line 127 and change the option `horizontal` to "left", then click "run" on the fiddle. Now see if notification opens left-aligned. Similarly, change the option to "center" and run the fiddle again. Now you get it?